# In reactJS how to wait for one api call to execute and then call next api

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In reactJS how to wait for one api call to execute and then call next api.

In my componentDidMount I am checking data length. Once the length is more than 4 in that case first I want to save and then I want to retrieve.

```js
    componentDidMount = () => {
        try {
               MyApi.getInstance()
                    .count()
                    .then(async (data: any) => {
                            await this.saveDefaultData(); // await is not working
                 this.getData(); 
                        
                    });
            } catch (error) {}
    
    } 


    this.saveDefaultData = () => {
            try {
               MyApi.getInstance().saveSystemDefault();
            } catch (error) {}
        };

this.getData = () => {
    try {
            MyApi.getInstance()
                .getAllData()
                .then((data: any) => {
                    // state update operation
                .catch();
        } catch (error) {
          Error handling
        }
    });
};
```

But both the call is going parlay how to make it sequentially.

Comment: How do you say it isn't working? 

Comment: ya because both the calls for saveData and getData are going parrally. let's consider if I don't have to return anything, in that case what should I do

Comment: Is this JavaScript or TypeScript? Coz this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: typescript. Mybad. I have just updated.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman You can see in `componentDidMount ` method I am able to achive as I can use `.then` since here I am updating data in loop so not returning anything and not using `.then` therefore problem is arising.

Comment: Got it... Did you check the answer by Lars?

Comment: ya working on that and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The await is not working because no return value is being declared so it has no promise to `await` if you change your `saveDefaultData` function to `return  MyApi.getInstance().saveSystemDefault();` it will wait for the promise to resolve. Async functions need a return value to be awaited properly

Comment: let's consider if I don't want to return anything, in that case what should I do

Comment: you can just add return anyhow this will result in the promise returning `undefined` you can just not use the returned `undefined`